# How to programmatically create pages from a single csv file

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to create a simple glossary website using Gatsby and a csv file as simple database. I used gatsby-transformer-csv plugin with help from their example and I managed to create the pages but I couldn't pull the data in each page in the template file.

I used this on my pages template file, field1: is the first value on my csv file (word) and field2 is the second value (definition). But it keeps showing error messages.

```
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import React from "react"
import Layout from '../components/layout';

export default ({ data }) => {
    const post = data.GlossaryCsv;
    const word = post.field1;
    const def = post.field2;
    return (
        <Layout>
                <h1> { word } </h1>
                <h4> { def } </h4>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
            glossaryCsv(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
            field1
            field2
        }
        }`
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Looks like you got a typo there? 'const post = data. **G**lossaryCsv', but in your query it's ' **g** lossaryCsv'

Comment: Here is the example, but it just list the letters. How can I create a page for each letter?
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-csv

Comment: you'd have to loop the data from csv and run createPage on each letter. You would be able to receive more help if you add more context, like your `gatsby-node.js`, and also show the error message that you got ^